# Connect FIS Relius (401k Plan Recordkeeper) to Plaid

Tags: plaid

We are a financial advisor who utilizes FIS Relius for recordkeeping services of small-business retirement plan participant accounts in trustee-directed (pooled investment accounts) retirement plans. Looking to connect our partners at FIS Relius into Plaid, which integrates with our portfolio management software, and they are requesting the following details to get started:

- The domain name of the aggregator for whitelisting
- IP address range

Once these details are secured they can move forward with setting up the API between the two platforms.

Have not been able to get in touch with Plaid to address the issue - there is no public facing contact phone number/email.

Comment: Contact form for Plaid: https://plaid.com/contact/